# SSH public key must be specified when running with AWS - error thrown while creating the kops cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I followed every steps as per the standard documentation described in both the aws & kubernetes. But still I get this error. May I know the reason behind this prompt?

Answer (score 0):

AWS prohibits running EC2 instances without assigning an SSH key to them. To resolve this you'll have to create a kops secret with you public SSH key like this:

```
kops create secret --name $NAME_OF_YOUR_CLUSTER sshpublickey admin -i $NAME_OF_THE_FILE_WITH_PUB_KEY
```

Then you can run `kops create cluster...` or `kops update cluster ... --yes`.